# Prefetch data in a separate thread in Caffe

Tags: python, multithreading, caffe, prefetch, pycaffe

Currently I am working with 3d volumetric data with Caffe in Python. In total I have 25 volumes, and from each one, I have to take subvolumes, and feed them through a convolutional network. The problem is that there might be thousands of these volumes, and currently I am saving them in hdf5 files, which works fine but uses a lot of hard disk. Also I am planning to do some data augmentation on the fly so I think it is better to use a prefetch technique in order to load the data in a seperate thread without blocking the training. I want something like this:

```
dataqueue=Queue
pool = Pool(processes=3)

#here I want to do this in groups of say 3 because each volume is very big

for idx,namepatient in enumerate(patients):
    pool.apply_async(workerv1,args=(idx,namepatient,path_patients,volsz,destres,samplesperpatient,dirname))

for i in xrange(iterations):
  net.blobs['data'].data[0:sizebatch,...] =dataqueue.get()
  solver.step(1)
```

So basically I want some threads that keep feeding data to the queue, but without blocking the main thread for doing the training. In the feeding data threadsI should do the subvolume sampling and augmentation if possible. Could anybody guide me in how to implement this.
I have checked this example https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn/blob/master/lib/roi_data_layer/layer.py but it only loads one image and put it into the queue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to do for multiple sub volumes at once, you can launch a seperate thread for trianing and a seperate multipurpose pool for data prefetching and augmentation. My explanation might be a bit terse. You might want to take a look at [LRCN Video Data](https://github.com/LisaAnne/lisa-caffe-public/blob/lstm_video_deploy/examples/LRCN_activity_recognition/sequence_input_layer.py) if you want to know in detail how its done.

Answer (score 0):

Caffe has built-in prefetching thread that prefetch data in parallel while the main thread does the training. It's implemented inside the base_data_layer and internal_thread files in include and src. I think this prefetching works good for most applications, but you can create more prefetching threads for different volumes if you need.